# I cannot seem to install ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

My Ubuntu installer cannot create an ext4 partition

The thing that shows up is always this:

[image]

I have nothing installed in my computer. (I just deleted and created a new ext4 partition using gparted. Please help!

I checked my hard drive using Ubuntu Disk Utility (from a live  CD) and it's as follows[image]

Comment: Have you tried with the whole disk unformatted? Remove the partition you have created and leave the disk unallocated. Ubuntu installation will create two the partitions it needs.

Comment: Your hard drive may be busted.

Comment: @user68186 yes, i have.

Answer (score 2):

Searching for "device reported invalid chs sector" shows:

- Your hard drive might be broken

If you have [a live-CD out of this list](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki/LiveCDs), you could test your hard drive with smartmontools:

The other thing I found was the ext4-bug, but thats a very special case (3 rare mount options + lazy unmount) and not yours.

Comment: Check the edits. I checked my hard drive with ubutu's built in disk utility and the result is as in the image above.

Comment: @Cipher: It shows "17 bad sectors", so maybe you should try some repair function, so that the file system knows it should not use those sectors.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem was solved my re-formatting it in ext3 filesystem. Looked like it was ext4 bug, but don't know what!